# How do you add a border to a chart in python pptx

Tags: python-3.x, python-pptx

I've got a stacked bar chart and I'd like to put a border around the chart but there is no 'line' attribute for the chart:

```
    from pptx.chart.data import ChartData
from pptx.enum.chart import XL_CHART_TYPE, XL_TICK_MARK, XL_LABEL_POSITION, XL_LEGEND_POSITION
from pptx.dml.color import RGBColor
from pptx.util import Inches, Pt

# define chart data 
chart_data = ChartData()
chart_data.categories = ['East', 'West', 'Midwest']
chart_data.add_series('Series 1', (19.2, 21.4, 16.7))
chart_data.add_series('Series 2', (10.2, 11.4, 6.7))
chart_data.add_series('Series 3', (2.2, 8.4, 1.7))



# add chart to slide
x, y, cx, cy = Inches(1), Inches(1), Inches(5), Inches(3.5)
ThisChart = ThisSlide.shapes.add_chart(
XL_CHART_TYPE.COLUMN_STACKED, x, y, cx, cy, chart_data
).chart # the '.chart' is getting the chart object from the chart creation


#Put a border around the chart *This is the part that not working *
ThisBorder = ThisChart.line # <--- there is no line attribute
ThisBorder.color.rgb = RGBColor(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00) # hex
ThisBorder.width = inches(0.1)

#Give the chart a title
ThisChart.chart_title.has_text_frame = True
ThisChart.chart_title.text_frame.text = "My Chart Title"

# Give the chart a legend
ThisChart.has_legend = True
ThisChart.legend.position = XL_LEGEND_POSITION.RIGHT
ThisChart.legend.include_in_layout = False
ThisChart.legend.font.size = Pt(11)

#add data labels
plot = ThisChart.plots[0] # The first Series
plot.has_data_labels = True # display the value on the bar
plot.overlap = 100 # make the bars stacked
data_labels = plot.data_labels
data_labels.font.size = Pt(11)
data_labels.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(0,0,0)
data_labels.number_format = "#,##0"


ThisChart.value_axis.has_minor_gridlines = False
ThisChart.value_axis.has_major_gridlines = False
ThisChart.value_axis.tick_labels.font.size = Pt(12)
ThisChart.value_axis.tick_labels.number_format = "#,##0"
ThisChart.category_axis.tick_labels.font.size = Pt(12)

# Colour the bars, I'm not going to really use these colours, just getting things working :)
ThisChart.series[0].fill.solid()
ThisChart.series[0].fill.fore_color.rgb = RGBColor(244,66,152) # Pink hex: F44298, RGB: 244,66,152
ThisChart.series[1].fill.solid()
ThisChart.series[1].fill.fore_color.rgb = RGBColor(66,134,244) # Blue hex: 4286F4, RGB: 66,134,244
ThisChart.series[2].fill.solid()
ThisChart.series[2].fill.fore_color.rgb = RGBColor(92,244,66) # Green hex: 5CF442, RGB: 92,244,66
```

Is there another way to make the chart area have a border? Just looking for a thin black border around the chart area that includes the legend. I'm planning to have four charts on the slide.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not yet implemented in `python-pptx`. If it were, it would be `Chart.plot_area.format.line`, in case you want to add a feature request for it on the GitHub repo.

In the meantime, you have two choices, three if you include "make do without" :)

The first is to include a chart formatted the way you want in the "starting" or "template" presentation, and use the `Chart.replace_data()` method to just change the data it depicts. This gives you really broad control, but it requires you know in advance how many charts you want and where.

The second approach is to use `lxml` level calls to manipulate the underlying XML to add the required elements and set the attributes appropriately. You can find some more information on this approach if you search on 'python-pptx workaround functions'.

Comment: Yes, quite right, I've fixed that. I authored both of them and sometimes mix them up like my children's names :)